# An uncaught Exception was encountered Error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

##### An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on bool

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\application\views\transaction\sale\cart_data.php

Line Number: 2

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\application\views\transaction\sale\sale_form.php
Line: 134
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\application\libraries\Template.php
Line: 14
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\application\controllers\Sale.php
Line: 26
Function: load

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sikan_v2\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

My Controllers: controllers/sale.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sale extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        check_not_login();
        check_admin();
        $this->load->model(['sale_m','item_m', 'supplier_m', 'stock_m']);
    
    } 

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model(['customer_m', 'item_m']);
        $customer = $this->customer_m->get()->result();
        $item = $this->item_m->get()->result();
        $cart = $this->sale_m->get_cart();
        $data = array(
            'customer' => $customer,
            'item' => $item,
            'cart' => $cart,
            'invoice' => $this->sale_m->invoice_no(),
        );
        $this->template->load('template', 'transaction/sale/sale_form', $data);
    }

    public function process()
    {
        $data = $this->input->post(null, TRUE);

        if(isset($_POST['add_cart'])) {
            $this->sale_m->add_cart($data);
        }

        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            $params = array("success" => true);
        } else {
            $params = array("success" => false);
        }
        echo json_encode($params);
    }

}
```

My Models: models/Sale_m.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sale_m extends CI_Model {

    public function invoice_no()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(MID(invoice,9,4)) AS  invoice_no
            FROM t_sale
            WHERE MID(invoice,3,6) = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y%m%d')";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        IF($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            $n = ((int)$row->invoice_no) + 1;
            $no = sprintf("%'.04d", $n);
        }else{
            $no = "0001";
        }
        $invoice = "MP".date('ymd').$no;
        return $invoice;
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }

    public function get_cart($params = null)
    {
        $this->db->select('*, p_item.name as item_name, t_cart.price as cart_price');
        $this->db->from('cart');
        $this->db->join('p_item', 't_cart.item_id = p_item.item_id');
        if($params != null) {
            $this->db->where($params);
        }
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('userid'));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }



    public function add_cart($post) 
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(cart_id) AS cart_no FROM t_cart");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            $car_no = ((int)$row->cart_no) + 1;
        } else {
            $car_no = "1";
        }

        $params = array(
            'cart_id' => $car_no,
            'item_id' => $post['item_id'],
            'price' => $post['price'],
            'qty' => $post['qty'],
            'total' => ($post['price'] * $post['qty']),
            'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('userid')
        );
        $this->db->insert('t_cart', $params);
    }

    

}
```

My View: transaction/sale/cart_data.php

```
<?php $no = 1;
if($cart->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($cart->result() as $c =>$data) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$no++?>.</td>
            <td><?=$data->barcode?></td>
            <td><?=$data->item_name?></td>
            <td class="text-right"><?=$data->cart_price?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?=$data->qty?></td>
            <td class="text-right"><?=$data->discount_item?></td>
            <td class="text-right"id="total"><?=$data->total?></td>
            <td class="text-center" width="160px">
            <button id="update_cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-item-edit"
            data-cartid="<?=$data->cart_id?>"
            data-barcode="<?=$data->barcode?>"
            data-product="<?=$data->item_name?>"
            data-price="<?=$data->cart_price?>"
            data-qty="<?=$data->qty?>"
            data-discount="<?=$data->discount_item?>"
            data-total="<?=$data->total?>"
            class="btn btn-xs btn primary">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Update
            </button>
            <button id="del_cart" data-cartid="<?=$data->cart_id?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete
            </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
} else { 
    echo '<tr>
    <td colspan="8"> class="text-center">Tidak ada item</td>
    </tr>';
} ?>
```

please help me solve the error

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Start from the view where `$cart` seems to be `null`. Then go to the controller where you set that variable and check what it is there. Then go to the `get_cart()`-method where you do the database request and check what it actually get and return. If it's not what you expect, then focus on that code to figure out why.

Comment: To add, the error is saying `$cart` is of type boolean which means it's not storing what you think or what you'd like it to store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with mysqli problems? Errors like mysqli\_fetch\_array(): Argument #1 must be of type mysqli\_result and such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/what-to-do-with-mysqli-problems-errors-like-mysqli-fetch-array-argument-1-m)

Answer (score 0):

It will return bool when there's any errors in your query. Check this function again:

```
public function get_cart($params = null)
{
    $this->db->select('*, p_item.name as item_name, t_cart.price as cart_price');
    $this->db->from('cart');
    $this->db->join('p_item', 't_cart.item_id = p_item.item_id');
    if($params != null) {
        $this->db->where($params);
    }
    $this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('userid'));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

I think it should be:

```
$this->db->from('t_cart');
```

If you check again and find no errors, you can use method: [last_query](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html) to get the query then try to query directly in phpmyadmin or MYSQL Workbench to check if there's any errors. Like this:

```
public function get_cart($params = null)
{
    // above source code
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $this->db->last_query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a

`var_dump($data)`

before calling this line to see if the 'cart' gets what you expect.

`$this->template->load('template', 'transaction/sale/sale_form', $data);`

My guess is that you are missing the result() at the end:

```
return $this->db->query("<your query>")->result();
```